# Listview Disable letter scroll in android

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have implemented a listview in my Application , but the listview shows letter scroll on  its right side, but i have not implemented it 
and it shows only on devices like 4.1.2 now i want to disable it, how is that done.
Thanks In advance
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want a scrollable listview just dont use a listview. Use a vertical linearlayout instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the fast scrolling like this:

```
listView.setFastScrollEnabled( false );
```